# Two parameters with custom URL. Rewrite in IIS, can't figure out syntax

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I've set this up and it works just fine
https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module

But what I want to do is alter the stored procedure that fires off so that I can have more parameters. In their sample rule, you end up with this

```
<rule name="DbProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{DB:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
```

So on the page I set a new variable that I called ENVIRON. What I hoped to do was have different rules for test and production. So I modified the RewriteTable to include a column for "environment".

What has me stumped is that I can't figure out how to pass two parameters to the stored procedure. I thought it would be as simple as something like this

```
<add input="{DB:{R:1},{ENVIRON}}" pattern="(.+)" />
```

I tried numerous other syntax but I keep getting the same 500.x error:

> Procedure or function 'GetRewrittenUrl' expects parameter '@env', which was not supplied

So my question is simple, when creating this setup, how does one pass more than a single parameter to the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module): *"The provider connects to a SQL Server database and executes a stored procedure that takes **a NVARCHAR input parameter** containing the input URL string and returns a one row, one column result set containing the output URL string of NVARCHAR type."*

Unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is not possible as such stored procedures can only accept a single parameter (which must be called ***@input***).

Answer (score 0):

So you can't use a second parameter, however, you can replace {R:1} with a delimited parameter to the database.

ie. {DB:{R:1}} could become {DB:{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}}

Then you can alter your stored procedure to handle that.